# jQuery Division with variables

Tags: jquery, css, width, divide

I'm new at jQuery and want to know if its possible to take some variables and get their division as CSS width. So far I'm here:

```
var x = $(".some-container").length;
var y = $("#some-div").width();
$(".container").css("width", "x / y");
```

thanks for any help!

Comment: `$(".container").width(x / y);`

Comment: `x / y` @OP seems to return a negative value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".container").css("width", (x / y));
```

OR

```
$(".container").css("width", function(){
 return (x / y);
});
```